# HTML inside PHP with concatenation operator?

Tags: php, html

```
if(empty($U_name)){
    $msg .= "Name can not be empty <br>";
}
if(empty($U_user_name)){
    $msg .= "Username can not be empty <br>";
}
echo "<div class='error'>".$msg."</div>";
```

here .(dot) is the concatenation operator.
could anyone please make me clear the code of the last statement.

Comment: Looks right to me. Are you getting any errors? You may want to set `$msg` before the if statement: `$msg = '';`

Comment: No i don't get any error but the last statement "how concatenation works" not clear to me?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: my question is how the html goes with php code.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: how the associated div tag applies to the $msg variable

Comment: This is not a duplicate per-say of the question linked to but it is a duplicate of a commonly asked question. Your code is fine you need to initialize your variable $msg first is all. You can not concatenate anything to a variable that does not exist yet. This is where the General Reference Question (duplicate) comes in.

Comment: Do not do this, use a controller to bind the message or at least something like this:  <html> <?php echo $msg ?> </html>